# case in sql stored procedure on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Based on a parameter I'd like to execute a different Update in my stored procedure.  I've tried many permutations of the code below, but I always have errors.

```
    @EmpID int = 0, 
@NewStatus nvarchar(10) = 0
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

select CASE   @NewStatus 

when    'InOffice' then 
     Update tblEmployee set InOffice = -1 where EmpID = @EmpID
when   'OutOffice' then 
    Update tblEmployee set InOffice = -1 where EmpID = @EmpID
when 'Home' then 
    Update tblEmployee set Home = -1 where EmpID = @EmpID

END
```

Comment: `CASE` in SQL Server **only** returns a single, atomic value - it's not designed to handle expressions or code blocks (like `switch` in C#)

Comment: Can you define "errors" - in particular when using Michael's correct syntax? What errors?

Answer (score 36):

Try this

```
If @NewStatus  = 'InOffice' 
BEGIN
     Update tblEmployee set InOffice = -1 where EmpID = @EmpID
END
Else If @NewStatus  = 'OutOffice'
BEGIN
    Update tblEmployee set InOffice = -1 where EmpID = @EmpID
END
Else If @NewStatus  = 'Home'
BEGIN
    Update tblEmployee set Home = -1 where EmpID = @EmpID
END
```

Comment: Who down voted me please post your reason, there is no syntax error or anything wrong with this answer.

Comment: Have another upvote! your answer helped me.  people should really post WHY they downvote something if its not obvious.

Comment: I'm guessing down votes are because your syntax includes THEN - which is not valid T_SQL http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx

Comment: And another upvote. Nothing wrong with this and it helped me too.

Answer (score 19):

`CASE` isn't used for flow control... for this, you would need to use `IF`...

But, there's a set-based solution to this problem instead of the procedural approach:

```
UPDATE tblEmployee
SET 
  InOffice = CASE WHEN @NewStatus = 'InOffice' THEN -1 ELSE InOffice END,
  OutOffice = CASE WHEN @NewStatus = 'OutOffice' THEN -1 ELSE OutOffice END,
  Home = CASE WHEN @NewStatus = 'Home' THEN -1 ELSE Home END
WHERE EmpID = @EmpID
```

Note that the `ELSE` will preserves the original value if the `@NewStatus` condition isn't met.

Comment: This happens to be my preferred method... since the optimizer will hit every option.  Using the If Structure (albeit easy to read and understand as well) the optimizer will only work against the condition met (whatever branch of the 'IF') when 1st executed.  This method aides in the execution plan being more accurate as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT  Salary FROM tbl_Salary WHERE Code=102 AND Month=1 AND Year=2020 )=0 THEN 'Pending'
WHEN (SELECT  Salary FROM tbl_Salary WHERE Code=102 AND Month=1 AND Year=2020 AND )<>0 THEN (SELECT CASE  WHEN ISNULL(ChequeNo,0) IS NOT NULL   THEN 'Deposit' ELSE 'Pending' END AS Deposite FROM tbl_EEsi WHERE  AND (Month= 1) AND (Year = 2020) AND )END AS Stat)
```