# T-SQL: Execute command in case block

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there any possible way to execute something like this in T-SQL?

```
CASE @@VERSION 
WHEN 'SQL Server 2005'
THEN Command_A
ELSE Command_B
END
```

This case block should pick Command_A if the server version is 2005. If not Command_B should get executed.

Comment: Yes with dynamic sql. But the version for my 2005 is: Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.5069.00 (X64)   Aug 22 2012 18:02:46   Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100482/case-in-sql-stored-procedure-on-sql-server

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is **not** a flow-control statement to execute code - it's an **expression** to return one of several possible values, depending on the conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the case is a "subcommand" of SELECT
you could achieve what you want with something like this:

```
declare @s varchar(255)
select @s = case @@VERSION 
when 'SQL Server 2005'
THEN 'command 1'
ELSE 'command 2'
END
exec (@s)
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work just fine, like this:

```
if (@@version like '%SQL Server 2014%') select '2014'
else select 'Other'
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/1983).

But if you're going to have there code that is not supported by the version you're running it in, you should either create separate procedures that you're going to call, or use dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic SQL for that

```
DECLARE @dynamicSql VARCHAR(max);
CASE @@VERSION
            WHEN 'SQL Server 2005'
                THEN @dynamicSql = 'Command_A'
            ELSE @dynamicSql = 'Command_B'
            END

    EXEC (@dynamicSql)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `CASE` to get the sql-server version:

```
SELECT CASE SUBSTRING(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')AS nvarchar(128)), 1, CHARINDEX('.', CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')AS nvarchar(128))) - 1)
       WHEN 7 THEN 'SQL Server 7'
       WHEN 8 THEN 'SQL Server 2000'
       WHEN 9 THEN 'SQL Server 2005'
       WHEN 10 THEN 'SQL Server 2008/2008 R2'
       WHEN 11 THEN 'SQL Server 2012'
       WHEN 12 THEN 'SQL Server 2014'  
       ELSE 'Unsupported' END AS DB_Version
```

Then you just need to execute dynamic sql according to the result.

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/1156/0)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, but i have already the right way to get the Server Version. My problem is to execute command_a or command_b in result of the Server Version in one Step.

Comment: Ok, but `@@Version` doesn't give you `'SQL Server 2005'` but something like `Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.5069.00 (X64) Aug 22 2012 18:02:46 Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)`

Comment: I know, thanks. But as i said, i have already a function wich gives me the right result.